# How to determine the Max property on a Relationship in Neo4j 2.2.3

Tags: neo4j

How do you *quickly* get the maximum (or minimum) value for a property of all instances of a relationship?  You can assume the machine I'm running this on is well within the recommended spec's for the cpu and memory size of graph and the heap size is set accordingly.

Facts:

- Using Neo4j v2.2.3
- Only have access to modify graph via Cypher query language which I'm hitting via PHP or in the web interfacxe--would love to avoid any solution that requires java coding.
- I've got a relationship, call it `likes` that has a single property `id` that is an integer.
- There's about 100 million of these relationships and growing
- Every day I grab new `likes` from a MySQL table to add to the graph within in Neo4j
- The relationship property `id` is actually the primary key (auto incrementing integer) from the raw MySQL table.
- I only want to add new `likes` so before querying MySQL for the new entries I want to get the max `id` from the `likes`, so I can use it in my SQL query as `SELECT * FROM likes_table WHERE id > max_neo4j_like_property_id`

How can I accomplish getting the max `id` property from neo4j in a optimal way?  Please indicate the create statement needed for any index as well as the query you'd used to get the final  result.

I've tried creating an index as follows:

```
 CREATE INDEX ON :likes(id);
```

After the index is online I've tried:

```
 MATCH ()-[r:likes]-() RETURN r.i ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

as well as:

```
 MATCH ()-[r:likes]->() RETURN MAX(r.id)
```

They work but take freaking *forever* as the explain plan for both indicate no indexes being used.

*UPDATE:* Holy $?@#$?!!!! It looks like the new schema indexes aren't functional for relationships even though you can create them and show them with `:schema`.  It also looks as if there's no way with cypher directly to create Legacy Indexes which look like they *might* solve this issue.

Comment: I would probably just store the max id you inserted last time somewhere in Neo4j or MySQL and update it after your batch of inserts is done.

Comment: Schema indexes were never meant for relationships, what you did was to create a node-label index for the label `:likes`

Comment: @MichaelHunger  I see.  I didn't expect neo4j to allow me to create an index on a non-existing node label, but your explaination makes sense.  I'm pretty sure I'll have to go the route of creating an additional way to track this--maybe just creating a tracking node with a single value IO update. I was hoping it would be something that would be possible intrinsicly.   Also sometimes I just want to grab a specific relationship by id--this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @MichaelHunger  Do you know if there is going to be a future plan to allow indexing on relationships via schema indexes or other wise?

Comment: I guess I could make each likes relationship a node, then instead of like TYPE relationship directly between two of the people nodes, I could make a wonky work around: `(n:person {id: 'bob'} )-->(:likes {id: 3})-->(:person {id: 'jim'} )`

Comment: You could do that, but it would much faster (and less expensive in neo4j resources) to follow one of the suggestions in @MichaelHunger's original comment.

Comment: I think you should only make them nodes if they are a relevant entity in your domain that many things link to. Otherwise relationships are ok.

Comment: There will be index supported per node relationship subselection. A global index wouldn't really help as you are looking for a single max property (and would be also quite wasteful).

Comment: @MichaelHunger yes, in this case a single entity in mysql or neo just to track the id is much less wasteful than global index.  But lets say the nodes were airports and relationships were flights and their was a property on the flights of 'fuel wasted'.  you might want to find what's the  fuel wasted for the worst 10000 direct flights with most fuel wasted  or something like that.  `MATCH (a:airport)-[f:flight]->(b:airport) ORDER BY flight.fuel_wasted DESC limit 10000`

Comment: @MichaelHunger  I get that something simplistic as the airport use case is better suited for the raw mysql, but it would be nice to be able to do all my DB activity on a single model--not have to jump back and forth between diff technologies especially if I ever get to point of skipping the raw data write to mysql and put it direclty into Neo4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to query relationship properties, it is generally a sign of a model issue.

The need of this query reveals you that you would better extract these properties into a node, that you'll then be able to query faster.

I don't say it is 100% the case, but certainly 99% of the people seen so far with the same problem has been demonstrating this model concern.

What is your model right now ?

Also you don't use labels at all in your query, `likes` have a context bound to the nodes.

Comment: I'm not using this property for general queries.  I'm using it to to determine the last relationship that was added to the graph.  In the OP description of how I'm populating the graph from another data source you can see how it's used.

Comment: I see now I unintentially created an index on nodes with the label `likes` instead of an index on a relationship type of `likes`

Comment: You can not create indexes on relationships types